# Существуют ли программы для автоматического преобразования c++ кода в uml?

Tags: uml

Существуют ли программы для автоматического преобразования c++ кода в uml?? Если существуют, то какие ?

Comment: Этот ресурс смотрели? https://scitools.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BoUML - http://bouml.fr/features.html

StarUML - http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/

Umbrello UML Modeller - http://uml.sourceforge.net/

Ну и тут еще можно посмотреть http://plg.uwaterloo.ca/~migod/uml.html